# Can data be restored from a hard drive after using magnets to wipe the data?

Tags: hardware, forensics, deletion

Can a 512GB SATA hard disk be successfully restored after using magnets to wipe off it's data?

From the movie: "The Core", https://youtu.be/g3KPSyNxnL8, rat using magnets to wipe his drive and puts his CDs in the microwave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only accepted way to erase data from a hard drive using magnetism is through a process called degaussing, which involves using an extremely powerful electromagnet which alternates its polarity thousands of times a second. It is the changing magnetic field which erases data, not the presence of magnetism itself. A human being cannot rotate a magnet fast enough to effectively degauss a hard drive. Most likely, if you put a strong magnet to a hard drive, you will just damage the delicate head inside it, but not irrecoverably destroy all the contents of the drive.

So yes, data most likely can be recovered from a hard drive that was exposed to a magnet held to it by a human.